# Объединить данные в таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

Вопрос такой

Имеется таблица с данными

| id | nm | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | PP | 17 июн 22 |
| 111 | MM | 17 июн 22 |
| 111 | GG | 21 июн 22 |
| 222 | PP | 14 июн 22 |
| 222 | MM | 14 июн 22 |
| 222 | GG | 15 июн 22 |
| 333 | PP | 15 июн 22 |
| 333 | MM | 15 июн 22 |
| 333 | GG | 15 июн 22 |
| 444 | GG | 18 июн 22 |
| 555 | GG | 23 июн 22 |

Необходимо получить следующее:

| id | nm | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | PP, MM | 17 июн 22 |
| 111 | GG | 21 июн 22 |
| 222 | PP,MM | 14 июн 22 |
| 222 | GG | 15 июн 22 |
| 333 | PP,MM,GG | 15 июн 22 |
| 444 | GG | 18 июн 22 |
| 555 | GG | 23 июн 22 |

По моим прдположениям можно сгруппировать по дате, но как поместить в nm несколько значений при этом не могу понять

Comment: какой SQL? они разные... для PostgreSQL например примерно так: ```select id,string_agg(nm,', '),dt from tableName group by id,dt```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Судя по всему идентично, по крайней мере документация говорит что ```string_agg``` в mssql - есть, и синтаксис ее таков же, проверьте, возможно заработает "как есть" :)

Comment: Да, это действительно сработало, спасибо!)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков оно с 2017й версии появилось емнип

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если SQL Server 2017 и выше, то:

```
SELECT  id,
        STRING_AGG(nm,', ') AS nm,
        dt
FROM #tableName
GROUP BY id, dt
```

Если порядок сгруппированных элементов важен, то так:

```
STRING_AGG(nm,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY nm) AS nm,
```

До SQL Server 2017 не было функции STRING_AGG, делали так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        id,
        STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + nm
                FROM #tableName tt
                WHERE t.id = tt.id AND t.dt = tt.dt
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS nm,
        dt
FROM #tableName AS t
```

---

Для проверки:

```
SELECT *
INTO #tableName
FROM
(
    VALUES
    (111,   'PP',   '17 июн 22'),
    (111,   'MM',   '17 июн 22'),
    (111,   'GG',   '21 июн 22'),
    (222,   'PP',   '14 июн 22'),
    (222,   'MM',   '14 июн 22'),
    (222,   'GG',   '15 июн 22'),
    (333,   'PP',   '15 июн 22'),
    (333,   'MM',   '15 июн 22'),
    (333,   'GG',   '15 июн 22'),
    (444,   'GG',   '18 июн 22'),
    (555,   'GG',   '23 июн 22')
) AS T(id, nm, dt)
```